# Is there a way to show suggestions related to the property in VSCode with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using Flutter in VSCode, and when I type a "TextAlign" for example, show me these suggestions:
random suggestions

[image]

and only when I scroll down a lot that it shows me the TextAlign options that I can use.

How can I make it look like this image, where the first suggestions are related to the property "TextAlign"?

related suggestions

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work, if anyone has the same issue, just disable "Dart: Auto Import Completions" in VSCode settings, and will show suggestions as in the second image of this post.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to now what the type that a property accepts, so hover on the textAlign property with your mouse, you will see that it's type is `TextAlign`,
no primitive type in dart have `TextAlign` type, so you will with that that `TextAlign` either a `class` type or an `Enum`, copy it then past it in the property then `ctrl + space` with vscode, if it's an `Enum`, it will shows directly and only the suggestions of it's values.

in your case the `TextAlign` is a `Enum`

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the cursor before coma`,` and keep typing like
[image]

[image]

Comment: Even with the cursor before coma don't show related to the textAlign.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLXbV.png

And when I start typing, it shows other suggestions not related to textAlign
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tMMj.png

Comment: You need to start typing for this , for `TextAling`, typing`T`. If you like to find unknown cases, you can hover over parameter name or better checking on docs

Comment: Even when I start typing it shows others things related, only when I'm near the end of the word that it shows. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tMMj.png

Comment: might be issue while using multiple extension for suggestion, try to disable others(snippet suggetion) only use flutter

Comment: Finally made it work, I had to deactivate "Dart: Auto Import Completions" in VSCode settings, and now it shows suggestions as expected. Thanks for the help!